# Format USB flash drive without partitions

Tags: linux, exfat

I have a 8GB flash drive that currently is split into 2 partitions. I want to format it with exFat as <strike>a single partition</strike> partitionless. I tried

> mkfs.exfat -n "8GB flash drive" -I /dev/sdc

but it says

```
mkfs.exfat: invalid option -- 'I'
```

Comment: You're using the wrong option: it should be `-v`.

Comment: Have you checked MANPAGE for this command ? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man8/mkexfatfs.8.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried that and it works:

Remove other file systems (only their "Magick Numbers" actually)

```
$ wipefs --all /dev/sdc
```

Then make the file system directly on the device file, without any additional options

```
$ mkfs.exfat -n "8GB flash drive" /dev/sdc
```

Comment: FWIW single partition != partitionless